# convert xml data to php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, xml

i have xml row column name with raw data i need to convert this into desirable array form :

```
    <RETS ReplyCode="0" ReplyText="Operation Success.">
<DELIMITER value="09"/>
<COLUMNS>
        AcresNum
        ADAFeaturesYN
        AdditionalFeatures
    </COLUMNS>
<DATA>
     0.0000 0   Ceiling Fan,Granite Counters,Multiple Attics,Security System</DATA></RETS>
```

I need to convert this in form of array like this :

```
array( [0] => array( ['AcresNum'] => 0.0000 , 
                     ['ADAFeaturesYN'] => 0),
       [1] => array( ['AcresNum'] => 1.0000 , 
                     ['ADAFeaturesYN'] => 1)  

     );
```

Comment: You can use `simplexml_load_string`(http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) if xml is in string or `simplexml_load_file`(http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) if you are xml file

Comment: i tried that but returns like that  Array
(
    [COLUMNS =>  AcresNum ADAFeaturesYN AdditionalFeatures AdditionalInformation   
)

Comment: Process `Array ( [COLUMNS => AcresNum ADAFeaturesYN AdditionalFeatures AdditionalInformation)` to create desired array

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is - in its current form - a "write me code" question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php)

```
$file = 'test.xml';
if (file_exists($file)) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
    print_r($xml);
} else {
    exit('Failed to open '.$file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a set of functions that will recursively convert any XML into an array, whatever is the depth and complexity. Including tags, properties etc etc, you name it... 
Note that any properties tags are set in the array with @attributes as the key, but can be anything you want.
in your case call it using

```
  $result=xmlstr_to_array($xmlstring);
```

Ones it s converted as an array, manipulate your stuff as you wish.

```
    // load xml string
    function xmlstr_to_array($xmlstr) {
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadXML($xmlstr);
        return domnode_to_array($doc->documentElement);
    }

    // convert nodes
    function domnode_to_array($node) {
    $output = array();
    switch ($node->nodeType) {
        case XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE:
        case XML_TEXT_NODE:
            $output = trim($node->textContent);
            break;
        case XML_ELEMENT_NODE:
            for ($i = 0, $m = $node->childNodes->length; $i < $m; $i++) {
                $child = $node->childNodes->item($i);
                $v = domnode_to_array($child);
                if (isset($child->tagName)) {
                    $t = ConvertTypes($child->tagName);
                    if (!isset($output[$t])) {
                        $output[$t] = array();
                    }
                    $output[$t][] = $v;
                } elseif ($v) {
                    $output = (string) $v;
                }
            }
            if (is_array($output)) {
                if ($node->attributes->length) {
                    $a = array();
                    foreach ($node->attributes as $attrName => $attrNode) {
                        $a[$attrName] = ConvertTypes($attrNode->value);
                    }
                    $output['@attributes'] = $a;
                }
                foreach ($output as $t => $v) {
                    if (is_array($v) && count($v) == 1 && $t != '@attributes') {
                        $output[$t] = $v[0];
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
    }
    return $output;
}

    //convert types
    function ConvertTypes($org) {
    if (is_numeric($org)) {
        $val = floatval($org);
    } else {
        if ($org === 'true') {
            $val = true;
        } else if ($org === 'false') {
            $val = false;
        } else {
            if ($org === '') {
                $val = null;
            } else {
                $val = $org;
            }
        }
    }
    return $val;
}
```

Comment: i already achieve that but i have column like this Array ( [COLUMNS => AcresNum ADAFeaturesYN AdditionalFeatures AdditionalInformation)

Comment: In this case, convert first in array and then explode you column element into multiple.

Comment: It s more of an array function rather than a xml problem. Doing it while parsing the xml is too tricky. Split the process.

Comment: i tried explode() for split value but it's not gonna happening

Comment: Once you have the xml as an array, I do not see what is the problem to explode and replace the element by the array.

Comment: i used delimiter one space but explode not happening.